# How to get the latest Document ID in Firestore using Swift iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am giving users the possibility to set up Project-Details in an app. 
Since there is also the opportunity to upload an image, i will have to make use of Firebase Storage. Because I want to give the users an overview of their projects combining the data and the uploaded picture I need to make a reference between the DocumentID in database and the ImageID in storage.

I thought about a two step approach: 1. Users are generating a Project -> User clicks "next" (document getting generated) 2. User uploads an image -> Image gets stored in Storage with Reference to the DocumentID of the just generated Project.

The goal is simply to link the Image to the Document ID of the project.

Can anyone give me a hint how to solve that problem? Here are my codes so far:

For the Project-Details:

```
// MARK: Store the Project Infos in Database

    // Check the fields and validate that the data is correct. If everything is correct, this method returns nil. Otherwise, it returns the error message

    func validateFields() -> String? {

        // Check that all fields are filled in
        if  txtLocation.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
           txtProjectTitle.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            txtProjectDescription.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            endDate.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
           beginnDate.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == ""  {

            return "Please fill in all fields."
        }

            return nil
    }



   @IBAction func saveProject(_ sender: Any) {


        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if  let user = user {

            let uid = user.uid

            // Validate the fields
            let error = validateFields()

            if error != nil {

                // There is something wrong with the fields, show error message
                showError(error!)
            } else {

        // Create cleaned versions of the data
            let projectTitle = txtProjectTitle.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let projectLocation = txtLocation.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let projectDescription = txtProjectDescription.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let projectBeginn = beginnDate.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let projectEnd = endDate.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        // Save stuff
        let db = Firestore.firestore()


                db.collection("Projects").addDocument(data: ["Project Title": projectTitle, "Project Location": projectLocation, "Project Description": projectDescription, "Project Start": projectBeginn, "Project Finish": projectEnd,  "uid": uid]) { (error) in

                       if error != nil {
                           // Show error message
                           self.showError("Error saving user data")
                       }
                   }

            }

        } else { self.showError("Please log out and log in again")}
 }


    // Error Handling for save
 func showError(_ message:String) {

        errorLabel.text = message
        errorLabel.alpha = 1
    }
```

And for the Image upload

```
//MARK: Imagepicker

      // Image Picker functions
      func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
          let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
          newImage.image = image

          picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }

      func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
          picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }


    // MARK: - Actions


    // Image Picker
    @IBAction func addImage(_ sender: Any) {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
             self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }))

               actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

               self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }


    //MARK: Upload Image


    @IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender: Any) {


    guard let image = newImage.image, let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
        self.showError("Something went wrong")
        return
    }

    let imageName = UUID().uuidString

    let imageReference = Storage.storage().reference()
                        .child("imagesFolder")
                        .child(imageName)
    imageReference.putData(data, metadata: nil) {(metadata, err) in
        if let err = err {
            self.showError("Something went wrong")
            return
        }

        imageReference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in
            if let err = err {
                self.showError("Something went wrong")
                return
            }
            guard let url = url else {
                 self.showError("Something went wrong")
                return
            }

            let dataReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("imageReferences").document()
            let documentUid = dataReference.documentID
            let urlString = url.absoluteString

            let imageUID = documentUid
            let data = ["Image UID": imageUID, "Image URL": urlString]

            dataReference.setData(data, completion: {(err) in
                if let err = err {
                    self.showError("Something went wrong")
                    return
                }
                UserDefaults.standard.set(documentUid, forKey: imageUID)
            })
         })
    }
        }

       // Error Handling for save
    func showError(_ message:String) {

           errorLabel.text = message
           errorLabel.alpha = 1
       }
```

So in best case I could do this even in one View Controller without the need of a two step approach. If it is not possible I would like to put the generated Document ID in

```
let data = ["Image UID": imageUID, "Image URL": urlString]
```

of

```
let dataReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("imageReferences").document()
            let documentUid = dataReference.documentID
            let urlString = url.absoluteString

            let imageUID = documentUid
            let data = ["Image UID": imageUID, "Image URL": urlString]

            dataReference.setData(data, completion: {(err) in
                if let err = err {
                    self.showError("Something went wrong")
                    return
                }
```

I would be very pleased if someone could help me. :)

Comment: Uploading is covered pretty well in the Storage [Upload Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) documentation. Take note of the examples where it says *// You can also access to download URL after upload.* so after you upload a file to storage, Firebase provides a download url that   can then be stored in Firestore. Because of that, you can name the image whatever you want because you will know the url to that image.